# How to dub a video with audio in android

Tags: android, media, mediamuxer

I want to make a dubbing app in Android. 
Flow of the app is:

1. Get video and audio from the gallery.
2. Reduce the original sound of Video file. And mix (Dub) the selected audio on this video file.
3. After mixing the audio on this video file save it in to external memory.

I am using MediaMuxer for this, but m not success. Please help me regarding this.

Regards,
Prateek

Answer (score 0):

even i was looking for the same to dub my video with an audio using mediaMuxer, MediaMuxer was a little difficult concept for me to understand  as i am beginner . i ended up refering this github code. https://github.com/tqnst/MP4ParserMergeAudioVideo
it was my saviour. really thanx to that person.
i just picked up the code i wanted from it, i.e dubbing a video with the audio i specify.

here is my code i used in my project below

```
private void mergeAudioVideo(String originalVideoPath,String AudioPath,String OutPutVideoPath) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Movie video = null;
    try {
        new MovieCreator();
        video = MovieCreator.build(originalVideoPath);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    Movie audio = null;
    try {
        new MovieCreator();
        audio = MovieCreator.build(AudioPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    List<Track> videoTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();
    for (Track t : video.getTracks()) {
        if (t.getHandler().equals("vide")) {
            videoTracks.add(t);
         //seperate the video from the orginal video
        }
    }
    Track audioTrack = audio.getTracks().get(0);// get your audio track to dub the video
    Movie result = new Movie();
    result.addTrack(videoTracks.get(0)); // add the video seprated from the originals
    result.addTrack(audioTrack); //add the track to be put in resul video

    Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(OutPutVideoPath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedWritableFileByteChannel byteBufferByteChannel = new BufferedWritableFileByteChannel(fos);
    try {
        out.writeContainer(byteBufferByteChannel);
        byteBufferByteChannel.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and here is the BufferedWritableFileByteChannel class to write the outputVideo data to the directory.

```
public class BufferedWritableFileByteChannel implements WritableByteChannel {
private static final int BUFFER_CAPACITY = 1000000;

private boolean isOpen = true;
private final OutputStream outputStream;
private final ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
private final byte[] rawBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_CAPACITY];

public BufferedWritableFileByteChannel(OutputStream outputStream) {
    this.outputStream = outputStream;
    this.byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(rawBuffer);
}

@Override
public int write(ByteBuffer inputBuffer) throws IOException {
    int inputBytes = inputBuffer.remaining();

    if (inputBytes > byteBuffer.remaining()) {
        dumpToFile();
        byteBuffer.clear();

        if (inputBytes > byteBuffer.remaining()) {
            throw new BufferOverflowException();
        }
    }

    byteBuffer.put(inputBuffer);

    return inputBytes;
}

@Override
public boolean isOpen() {
    return isOpen;
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    dumpToFile();
    isOpen = false;
}
private void dumpToFile() {
    try {
        outputStream.write(rawBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.position());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

and dont forget to add the libraries in your project.

this may not be the exact answer to your question. but atleast it will able to shed some light on the probable solution.